# How to conceptually understand the sine dot product?

Tags: vectors, products

I have an definition that is calculating the angle between two vectors:

$\sin(\alpha) = -a \cdot b$

(the sign $\cdot$ stands for a dot product, and $a$ and $b$ are unit vectors).

I understand that the dot product when equal to cosine of an angle is just the angle between the two vectors, but what does it mean when the dot product is equal to the sine of an angle?

Here are the equations and a diagram for how the angle want to be computed as well as a [link to the paper](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/biomechanical/article-standard/105/2/136/397206/A-Joint-Coordinate-System-for-the-Clinical):

[Equations for calculating angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZSD6.png)

[Axes for equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8mu6.png)

Comment: Where did you find this? It’s simply wrong in general. Are you perhaps misreading a cross product?

Comment: I added the paper and some diagrams with where I obtained this, it's definitely using a dot product

Comment: The paper is behind a paywall. Based on your figures, however, it seems the "flexion" is **not** the angle between $\mathbf e_2$ and $\mathbf K.$ The angle between those vectors appears to be $90$ degrees when flexion is zero, and increases as the flexion increases.

Comment: It's just a relationship. You can check more about this https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/dot-cross-products/v/proof-relationship-between-cross-product-and-sin-of-angle

Answer (score 0):

As the equation $\sin\alpha =-a\cdot b$ is equivalent to  $\sin(-\alpha)=a\cdot b,$ or $$a\cdot b = \cos(π/2+\alpha),$$ it follows that the angle between the vectors cannot be $\alpha,$ but possibly $\alpha+π/2.$

Comment: Dear Downvoter, I'd like to learn what I did wrong. If you'd please explain, I mean. :)